# ByteCode not present in APK dex after MultiDex in Unity

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine, android-multidex

I had an error in my **Unity** game that says:

```
 E/Unity: AndroidJavaException:
     java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.app.NotificationChannel
```

I used Gradle to **apply MultiDex** since the method count was large.

I analyzed the APK with Android studio and I saw that `byteCode` *was not available* in the dex code (see screenshot)

[image]

*I could not find this class in other DEXes.*

Is there something wrong with multidex process and is the code not really in the class path?

**TL; DR**

**Unity** with **MultiDex** causes `NoClassDefFoundError`. Why?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want a class (or method, etc) to be present in the Primary dex (which is first started and includes all necessarry methods), you should create a `multidex-config` file and add it there. Thus, the code you need will be present in the main dex file.

To define custom config for your multidex, follow one of these after applying multidex.

#### 1. Use text file as config

The file you specify in `multiDexKeepFile` should contain one class per line, in the format `com/example/MyClass.class`. For example, you can create a file called `multidex-config.txt` that looks like this:

```
com/example/MyClass.class
com/example/MyOtherClass.class
```

Then you can declare that file for a build type as follows:

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
            multiDexKeepFile file('multidex-config.txt')
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Remember that Gradle reads paths relative to the build.gradle file, so the above example works if multidex-config.txt is in the same directory as the build.gradle file.

#### 2. Use proguard rule

The multiDexKeepProguard file uses the same format as Proguard and supports the entire Proguard grammar. For more information about Proguard format and grammar, see the Keep Options section in the Proguard manual.

The file you specify in `multiDexKeepProguard` should contain -keep options in any valid ProGuard syntax. For example, `-keep com.example.MyClass.class`. You can create a file called `multidex-config.pro` that looks like this:

```
-keep class com.example.MyClass
-keep class com.example.MyClassToo
```

If you want to specify all classes in a package, the file looks like this:

```
-keep class com.example.** { *; } // All classes in the com.example package
```

Then you can declare that file for a build type as follows:

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
            multiDexKeepProguard file('multidex-config.pro')
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

> **Note**: This issue is only for apps that have MinSDK version 20 or lower (MinSDK 21 or higher supports it natively since it uses ART)

[Reference](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex#multidexkeepfile-property)